# How to add twitter and website handles to my spl-token to show in solscan?

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, metaplex, spl, solscan

I have created an spl-token and added metadata using metaplex createMetadataInstruction. I have added twitter and website links in uri but it is not showing in solscan and even I tried by adding external_url, It is also not working. Can anyone please help me how to add external website link/twitter handle for my token to show in my token page in solscan

Comment: It's better if you speak with the solscan team regarding this

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the address of the token so readers can look at and debug the metadata itself.